# Typeerror : Newey West for OLS in python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, statsmodels, statistical-test

I'm trying to run OLS regression using Newey West *t*-statistics in python using statsmodels.

My code is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5,7,4,5,6,4,7,8,9],
                   'b':[3,5,6,2,4,6,7,8,7,8,9]})
reg = smf.ols('a ~ b',data = df).fit(cov_type='HAC',cov_kwds={'maxlags':1})
```

When I run this it gives the error:
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not '_NoValueType'

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what is wrong in my code. As 'a' and 'b' have same length there is no NoValueType.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

code runs perfectly, There might be some other issue. see the image: [image]

Comment: Okay. What might be the issue? I am using spyder. Also are you using jupyter notebook?